# добавить еще одно условие: проверить класс в .parentNode

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Помогите доделать код, слабоват в знании языка - приходится допиливать из каких-то готовых кусочков разного кода.

Есть ряд инпутов которые выглядят так

```html
<p><input id="checkbox4" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="30" name="check" /> <label for="checkbox4">4</label></p>
```

написана уже проверка, которая сравнивает значения по определенным условиям и добавляет класс с родителю: p class="none">

И есть другой кусочек, который выбирает\снимает значения с этого списка.

```js
(function () {
    var inputs = document.getElementById('checklist').getElementsByTagName('input');
    document.getElementById('checkAll').addEventListener('click', function checkme(e, check) {
        check = check === undefined ? false : true;
        for (var i = 0, inputs_len = inputs.length; i < inputs_len; i++) {
             
            if (!check && !inputs[i].checked) {
                checkme(e, true);
                return;
            }
            inputs[i].checked = check;
        }
    });
})();
```

Нужно добавить доп условие которое бы проверял класс родителя элемента inputs[i].parentNode.class и если он равен none (или НЕ равен) - тогда уже ставил check  / т.е. работал со всеми инпутами кроме тех, у кого родитель class="none"

Я уже и так, и сяк... и все никак

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать `inputs[i].parentNode.classList.contains("none")`.

`classList.contains` проверяет, есть ли данный класс у элемента (вернет true или false).

Подробнее прочитайте [в документации mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: Да, большое спасибо! заработало. Без ".contains" - пробовал, не получалось.

Comment: Пожалуйста) Если вам ответ подходит, отмечайте его как подходящий.